# How to remove an option from a multiselect attribute in Magento?

Tags: php, magento

I am working in some stuff where I'm programmatically creating multiselect attributes and their options. I also need to programmatically remove an option from the multiselect attribute.
For creating purpose I used this flow

```
    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_code = 11;
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $value['option'] = array('some_data');
    $result = array('value' => $value);
    $attribute->setData('option',$result);
    $attribute->save();
```

However, When I try to remove an option in the same manner, it does not work. I'm trying the below code.

```
    $attribute_model = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute');
    $attribute_code = 11;
    $attribute = $attribute_model->load($attribute_code);

    $value['option'] = array('some_data');
    $result = array('value' => $value);

    $attribute->unsetData('option',$result);  // attempt 1
    $attribute->unsetData('some_data');  //attempt 2

    $attribute->save();
```

I have tried both attempt 1 and 2 but got no result.
How should I achieve that?

**Edit:**
`print_r($attribute->getData());` gives me this result.

`Array
(
    [attribute_id] => 133
    [entity_type_id] => 4
    [attribute_code] => test_attr
    [attribute_model] => 
    [backend_model] => eav/entity_attribute_backend_array
    [backend_type] => varchar
    [backend_table] => 
    [frontend_model] => 
    [frontend_input] => multiselect
    [frontend_label] => Tags For Promo
     .
     .
    [frontend_input_renderer] => 
    [is_global] => 0
    [is_wysiwyg_enabled] => 0
    [is_used_for_promo_rules] => 1
)`

Comment: Can you please give result of this code ? print_r($attribute->getData());

Comment: check edit @user3793635

Comment: what you remove from above array result ?

Comment: You didn't get my question. This is the attribute object. And I want to remove an option available for that attribute. Consider, I have one multiselect attribute color, now I can have options such as red, black, yellow. I want to remove red from the available options.

Comment: Please pass currect attribute code and after prit result so i can see exact result of object and after i can give some sugesstion to you.

Comment: I passed attribute code 133 and got that output and gave you the output.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83852/discussion-between-user3793635-and-elembivos).